# How to extract class variables and class methods from a java file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, data-structures, file-handling

```
private int OutsideFUnction(){
    int yoho;
}

public class Blog implements Subject {

private List<Observer> observers;
    private String article;
    private boolean changed;int Manaky; int Chahal; String letssee;

    public Blog() {
        this.observers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void register(Observer obj) {
        int insideRegister;
        if(obj == null) throw new NullPointerException("Null Observer");
        if(!observers.contains(obj)) observers.add(obj);
    }
    @Override
    public void unregister(Observer obj) {
        observers.remove(obj);
    }
    
    public String IAMNotAtStart;
    @Override
    public void notifyObservers() {
        List<Observer> observersLocal = null;
        System.out.println("HOOOOOO")
        if(!changed) return;
        
        observersLocal = new ArrayList<>(this.observers);
        this.changed = false;
        
        for(Observer obj: observersLocal){
            obj.update();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Object getUpdate(Observer obj) {
        return this.article;
    }
    
    public void postBlog(String words){
         System.out.println("New Article Posted:"+words);
         this.article = words;
         this.changed = true;
         notifyObservers();
    
    }
    
}


private nicheWalaFunction OutsideFUnction(){
    int lettestNicheWala;
}
```

I have the above java file. I am reading from this file using Python. My goal is to extract class variables and methods from this file. How can I do that? I don't want variables defined inside a method to be labeled as class variables or methods defined outside the class to be termed class methods. Please guide anyone, how can I do this via a Python snippet.

Comment: A good place to start would be to find a parser for Java written in Python.

Comment: @chepner the goal is to create my own for that .... can you solve the above problem via regular expressions or string manipulation?

Comment: No, regular expressions are going to be far from suitable. You're going to want to start with a proper grammar (which I assume will be context-free) and write a parser. There are lots of parser-generator tools that will take a suitably formatted grammar and give you a working parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Python parser for Java, I recommend [javalang](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang).